# SystemJS - TypeScript loader use cases

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

I have a question regarding following TypeScript plugin for SystemJS :

https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/

Here is its description

> A plugin for SystemJS which enables you to System.import TypeScript files directly. The files are compiled in the browser and compilation errors written to the console.

I wonder what would be the **use cases** of such plugin.

- Why would developers import directly ts files and compile them in the browser instead of compiling them during development and import js files ?
- Won't it reduce performance and load time to do it in browser ?
- Is it supposed to be used only in development environment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

plugin-typescript author here. In-browser compilation is strictly a development tool, in production you would use systemjs-builder (in combination with plugin-typescript) to create a single file containing all of the transpiled javascript.

Since the plugin was originally developed, a number of new workflows have become available when using typescript & systemjs (typescript single-file transpilation, vscode, systemjs hot-reloading, typescript system.register output, to name a few...) - Which one is right for you will depend on the size of your application, the platform/server you are using, and your own personal preferences.

Answer (score 1):

No one in their right mind would compile/transpile in the browser for production; it's the equivalent of sending a turtle to get your mail because you don't like walking.

This is strictly a development tool for helping TypeScript devs avoid having to constantly compile after every change, with the added benefit of providing features like hot reloading.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
What do you mean by "helping TypeScript devs avoid having to constantly compile after every change" ? It can be automated by most IDE or even with the TypeScript compiler in watch mode. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/tsconfig.html#typescript-compiler

Comment: System watchers have a habit of consuming a lot of resources, and if your project is sufficiently large (say, 100k LOC) you're gonna have a lot of stuff in-memory for incremental builds. With the loader you don't have to worry about that at all.